# Where can I ask about my master's thesis idea?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding the idea I'd like to implement for my master's thesis (in the software development field) and I'm not sure whether I should ask it on Stack Overflow, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) or [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour).

I'd like to receive others' opinions regarding it:

- whether it has enough complexity for a master's degree
- if it is clearly defined
- receive possible further ideas

Comment: Your advisor's office. These are all things your advisor will be able to tell you.

Comment: Asking for opinions is off-topic on every site in the network.

Comment: People ask questions like this at Academia.SE all the time, but that doesn't mean you should ask there. It would be closed and someone would possibly suggest to you in a comment to ask your advisor - that's what they are for, like Thomas says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### As mentioned in the comments, these would probably not work as a question on our network

- First of all, you can’t post those all in one question, as that would get closed as "Needs More Focus"
- About your first question, that seems opinion based, so likely couldn’t work
- Your second question would most likely be opinion based too.
- Your third question is both opinion based *and* a list question

#### Other alternatives

- As mentioned in the comments, going to your advisor's office might be worthwhile
- Other sites, like Quora and Reddit possibly.
- A chat room **might** work. There are lots of smart people in chat, and if you choose the correct room some people might be willing you to give you feedback.